# Get information from a graph image

Tags: c#, image-processing, multidimensional-array, pixel

[image]

In this image black colour graph is in the white background. I want to get the pixel length between the two peak waves in the graph and the average amplitude (height of the peak) of the peak waves.

I'm stuck with the logic to implement this code.can anyone help me to implement this. I'm using C#

```
public void black(Bitmap bmp)
{
         Color col;
             for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++)
             {
                for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Width; j++)
                {
                        col = bmp.GetPixel(j, i);
                        if (col.R == 0) //check whether black pixel
                        {
                            y = i;  //assign black pixel x,y positions to a variable
                            x = j;
                        }

                }                           
            }
 }
```

my supervisor told i have to use a 2D array to store increments and decrements(start point pixel value and end point pixel value of each increment and decrement) of the line to get these values.But i haven't sufficient coding skills to apply that logic to this code.

Comment: do you store the points somewhere? e.g. List<Point> ??

Comment: not yet..what is the best way to store these pixel values? 2D array or arraylist

Comment: maybe a List<[Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9b80s6c.aspx)> ? you could loop the list, and look for the two highest point.Y-Values, and after subtract point1.X - point2.X... smth like that?

Comment: but problem is how we separate two peaks from others? because every peaks haven't same y values and sometimes nearest pixels around the highest peak can have more y value than other peaks

Comment: Point p = myList.Max(t => t.Y) < should return the point with the highest Y-Value. and for the second point, hmpf, you could remove the "p" from the list, and search again for the .Max(t=> t.Y) ?? just an idea, i dont know :)

Comment: that logic can't use here.because every peaks haven't same y values and sometimes nearest pixels around the highest peak can have more y value than other peaks. example (highest peak have 20 pixel height and next highest peak(wave peak) has 15 pixel height.But other pixels around the highest peak  have 19,18,17,16 pixel values..I think you understand the problem here

Comment: i see yes, but how do you define a "Wave"? e.g. Y-Values: 16 17 18 19 20 19 18 17 18 19 20 19 18 17 two Waves? a new wave starts when it is like: n+1 n n+1?

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

```
        int width = img.Width;
        int height = img.Height;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            Color pixelColor = img.GetPixel(x, y);
        if (pixelColor.R == 0 && pixelColor.G == 0 && pixelColor.B == 0)               
            //listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("x:{0} y:{1}", x, y));

              textBox1.Text = (String.Format("x:{0} y:{1}", x, y));


    }
    }
```